# Echo back status to same page before completing the task in php

Tags: php

I have a `main.php` page. after clicking on submit button it will call two more php pages one by one.
eg: `sub1.php` and `sub2.php`. and these two php's will take around 5 min to complete the task.

what I want to know is once we clicked on `submit` button in `main.php`, first it will call `sub1.php`. before calling, it should echo back message saying that `sub1.php` triggered to `main.php` and also after completion of the `sub1.php`, it should echo back `sub1.php` task completed and `sub2.php` triggered.

Note that `sub1.php` will take minimum 5 min to complete. so first message will echo in `main.php` before calling `sub1.php` after completion of `sub1.php` then only second message should display.

Could you please help on this. I hope the requirement is clear.

Comment: Please paste relevant code as well

Answer (score 0):

You can control when and what is send by using the PHP buildin [output control functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php).

You can send something by echoing it and afterwards flushing the output buffer

```
for ($i = 0; $i<10; $i++){

    echo "<br> Line to show.";
    echo str_pad('',4096)."\n";   

    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(2);
}
```

Example taken from [PHP Manual: flush](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php)

Comment: @DHSan: Actually i didn't get your answer! where should i add this code? i mean before calling sub1.php or after completion of sub2.php?

Comment: @DHSan: Your script is worked fine but it's echo the line before header field. not in body. Could you please help.

Comment: @DHSan: your code is working fine in google chrome not in IE. Could you please help me to execute same in IE?